# Is it possible to reference ViewData within a script block in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to add a click handler for a button using jQuery, but the handler needs to reference data supplied by the controller.  Is there a way to access ViewData in a script block in ASP.NET MVC?  Or do I need to construct the script in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script block is within the ASP.NET page then you can reference it...

e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#group-edit-form').validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: '<%=Url.Action("ValidateGroupName", new { id = ViewData["GroupId"] }) %>?parentId=' + getParentId()
                }
            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: getMessage (7002),
                    remote: '<%= ((MessagingModel)ViewData["Messages"]).GetMessage (9001) %>'
                }
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```

When the page is processed by the runtime engine, everything within the <% ... %> blocks is evaluated, regardless of it's location in the page.

Comment: Do you get Intellisense when you do this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, VS reads it as part of the string, at least in the sample above ):

Comment: VS 2008 Gives you intellisense on your aspx pages.

Comment: I'm not getting intellisense either inside a script block or inside an HTML tag.

Comment: I don't get Intellisense when its inside a script block. For scenarios like above ill create the tag outside the script block for intellisense and then copy'n'paste it into the script tag area. Kinda clunky.